# path based routing for ecs service is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

[image: path-based-routing]

I have an alb pointing to my ecs service registered to target-group-one. The DNS of the load balancer works fine and able to print the message from my simple apache webserver. However when I configure path based routing like in the image attached and the add the path to the the DNS url ......com/gci, I get the error message **The requested URL was not found on this server.**

What am I missing or not doing right?

Comment: Does your ECS service actually have path `/gci` if you query it without alb?

Comment: @Marcin Nope I havent configured any path for the ecs service yet. Do I have to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your actual httpd server does not respond to `/gci` without ALB, then it will not work with ALB. The path rule that you configured **only forwards** the query to your target group (TG).

So if the rule matches `www.example.com/gci`, ALB will just forward the query to the associated TG. This means that your ECS service still must correctly respond to `/gci` path.

In other words, the forwarding rules of ALB **do not re-write** the paths.

Comment: Thanks very much @Marcin, I am new to httpd servers, any clue how I can make my server respond to /gci path

Comment: @Theonestar Its application specific. So you have to add such path to your application. But if you don't have it, why would you create rule for it in ALB?

Comment: Basically what I am seeking to do is to have the same alb point to one target group based on a certain path and then another target group based on a different path. That way have same alb for multiple services. I am not sure if this is the best way to do it ?

Comment: @Theonestar You can do this of course, but the applications on the instances must respond correctly to the paths. ALB can't string `/gci` from the request before it forwards it to your instance. For that, you could maybe setup nginx on the instances. So ALB would forward request `/gci` to nginx on the instance, nginx would strip `/gci` and forward the request to your application. But if you can, easier would be to use host routing. So you would use `gci.example.com`, instead of `example.com/gci`. For that you would have to have some domain name in Route53 for example.

Comment: ah okay, I see thanks I would look into those options

Comment: @Theonestar How did it go? Any progress?

Comment: sure, I just create a path in my application with the index html that I want serve and from there my app responded to the path and so does the load balancer. Thanks for the tips

Comment: @Marcin can you please look at this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67671252/nginx-static-files-404-with-django-swagger-rest-api
I am stuck for 2 days.

Comment: @AliHassanQureshi Not much of a django expert I am, thus can't help much with new question. Sorry.